# jquery ajax prevent form submit if username is unavailable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

i am using this script to check username availability, it works but the form is submitted even if the username is unavailable. i tried to use event.preventdefault but, i don't know to use it correctly how can i prevent the form to be submitted?

```
<script>
    function checkAvailability() {
        $("#loaderIcon").show();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "check_availability.php",
            data: 'username=' + $("#username").val(),
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#user-availability-status").html(data);
                $("#loaderIcon").hide();
            },
            error: function() {}
        });
    }
</script>
```

here is the form

```
<form id="defaultForm" action="index1.php" method="post" class="registration-form">
    Username
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="username" onBlur="checkAvailability()" id="username">
    <br><span id="user-availability-status"></span> Password
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="sub">Submit</button>
```

here is check_availability.php

```
<?php
    require_once("connect.php");
    if(!empty($_POST["username"])) {
      $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE username='" . $_POST["username"] . "'");
      $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
      $user_count = $row[0];
      if($user_count>0) {
         echo "<span class='status-not-available'><p style='text-align:center'> Username Not Available</p></span>";
      }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please indent your code and show us the complete code. Where is `checkAvailability` called?

Comment: Umm ofcourse it does.You need to use preventDefault, check on success the value returned and if it`s the correct one, submit the form

Comment: @Mihai i tried, but i dont know where to use it..

Comment: Any reason you call it onBlur and not on submit?

Comment: @Mihai i want to check live availability without submitting

Comment: Show your whole form

Comment: @Mihai i have edited and included whole form and check_availability.php

Answer (score 0):

Remove the function call in your HTML

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#defaultForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $("#loaderIcon").show();
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
            url: "check_availability.php",
            data: 'username=' + $("#username").val(),
            type: "POST"                
    }).success(function(data) {
      $("#user-availability-status").html(data);
                $("#loaderIcon").hide();
        if (data!= "<span class='status-not-available'><p style='text-align:center'> Username Not Available</p></span>")  
          self.submit();
    }).error(function() {
        alert('error');
    });
});

 });
```

Comment: @MahimParsai Use something like httpfox for firefox to see the headers.To be clear do you want the from submitted if it returns 'Username Not Available' or not?If yes change `data!=` to `data==`

Comment: if username is not available then the form should not be submitted4

Comment: @MahimParsai Any errors in the console?Did you check the headers?